# How do I dismiss file structure view in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.4 (Community Edition). How do I dismiss the file structure view (Navigate > File Structure)? I've been hitting the <kbd>esc</kbd> with no results; it stays there until I either choose an item in the list or click elsewhere with my mouse pointer (which is very inconvenient to me).

Comment: ESC works fine here.

Comment: Yeah, it was due to some peculiar behavior with escape functionality in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was due to the <kbd>esc</kbd> being used as primary keyboard shortcut for a few other keyboard shortcuts. I'm using Emacs keybindings and I think they were set there by default. The escape function was mapped to <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>, which I already knew. To resolve this issue, I looked for all shortcuts whose primary key was <kbd>esc</kbd>, and remove that particular binding (or replaced them with something I'm more comfortable with). I also updated the mapping of escape to only use single key press.

I actually also set another binding to the escape functionality, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, which also doesn't work to dismiss the file structure view. I think within the context of file structure view, the IDE follows a slightly different set of keybindings so no matter what I map to the escape functionality, it will only honor the single key press of <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Comment: I had the same issue -- I'm using Emacs keybindings and escape was assigned to many actions. I removed all the extra assignments and now I can escape the File Structure window.